# Heroku Crash on success

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have a node app that runs once a day. It runs successfully with scheduler and is set up as a worker. The issue is Heroku keeps restarting the worker on successful exit which is the build process. Is there a way to turn off these crash messages and restarts for successful exits? They quickly fill my log files.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by not having a worker at all. I just run scheduler with an `npm run build && npm run prod` script. Also keeps dyno costs really low.